# Adding CORS support to a legacy asp.net soap service

Tags: asp.net, soap, cors, asp.net-3.5

For the purposes of allowing developers to connect to a development server, I'd like to enable CORS. On the development server, I've added the following web.config options:

```
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:3000" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
```

When I hit the ASMX and the WSDL (e.g. `/SomeService.asmx?WSDL`), I see the headers. However, when the client-library that my development partners are using hit the service, it immediately perform an `OPTIONS` request against the target method:

```
OPTIONS /SomeService.asmx/GetAll HTTP/1.1
etc.
```

Again, the appropriate CORS headers are present, but the server gives an 500 status code, and the subsequent *real* request doesn't occur. The same error occurs if a `GET` verb is used in place of the `OPTIONS` request.

I presumably need to handle non-`POST` requests in my soap service (specifically `OPTIONS`). But, I'm not even sure where to start. I've tried adding this to the web config:

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet" />
    <add name="HttpPost" />
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

And that permits `GET` requests to go through; but they process as though they were full `POST`s, and `OPTIONS` still fail.

**Is there a simple way to handle custom and/or `OPTIONS` verbs in a legacy, asp.net (.net 3.5) ASMX/SOAP service?** Or, is there a quicker way to give client-side developers access a development server's services?

Comment: After I posted this, my development partners found a solution that involves adding a proxy to their build and test service, eliminating the need for CORS. So, solving this is no longer *critical* for me; though I'm still *very interested* in what the server-side solution would be ...